# Use GPU in Visual Stduio C# for image comparison

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencl, gpu

I am new to image processing. I have a portion of an image that I have to search in the whole image by comparing pixels. I need to get the coordinates of the small image present in the complete image.

So, I am doing

```
for int i = 0 to Complete_Image.Lenght
 for int j = 0 to Complete_Image.Height
  for int x = 0 to Small_Image.Lenght
   for int y = 0 to Small_Image.Height
    if Complete_Image[i+j+x][i+j+y] == Small_Image[x][y]
     Message "image found at coordinate x, y"
     Break
```

It is a simple pixel-matching algorithm that finds a certain portion of a image in a complete image by comparing pixels.

It is very time-consuming. For example, if I have to find coordinates of a 50X50 image in a 1000 X 1000 image, it will take 1000 X 1000 X 50 X 50 pixel color comparisons.

So:

> - Is there a better way to do image comparison in C#?
> - Can I use AMD Radeon 460 GPU to do this comparison thing in parallel? Or at least some part of the algorithm using GPU power?

Comment: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/hybridizer-csharp/

Comment: You could make this lightening speed even without the gpu. by using some smarts, pinned memory, pointer access and parallel processing. however gpu or not, its how you go about this that will speed it up the most. your current algorithm has a large time complexity and very inefficient

Comment: How often do the pixels of two images match up perfectly? Are you sure this is the kind of search you want?

Comment: There will be only one exact match. I have a portion of a screenshot that I have to find in the complete screenshot and get the coordinates of it. There will only one exact match. Is there a better algorithm and/or a GPU processing?

Comment: Obviously gpu will be faster, it depends how fast you want to go, ive got it under a 10th of a second for a 5000*3000 image looking for 300*300 image, without parallel in non gpu., apposed to the original algorithm, which run at about 10 seconds. however i am just tweaking a parallel version so i should be able to get it faster again

Comment: Please whenever you finish a parallel processing version, do post it here. And I was wondering if GPU's 700+ cores can be used to send one image matching loop to one GPU core, So, that it will take like 1 ms to compute whole image processing.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway i have run out of time, and might be able to finish the parallel version later.

The premise is passively walking across the sub image, if it finds a full line pixels matches, it the does a sub loop to compare the whole sub image

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static bool CheckSubImage(int* m0, int* s0, Rectangle mR, Rectangle sR, int x, int y, out Point? result)
{

   result = null;
   for (int sX = 0, mX = x; sX < sR.Width && mX < mR.Right; sX++, mX++)
      for (int sY = 0, mY = y; sY < sR.Height && mY < mR.Bottom; sY++, mY++)
         if (*(m0 + mX + mY * mR.Width) != *(s0 + sX + sY * sR.Width))
            return false;

   result = new Point(x, y);
   return true;
}

protected override Point? GetPoint(string main, string sub)
{
   using (Bitmap m = new Bitmap(main), s = new Bitmap(sub))
   {
      Rectangle mR = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, m.Size), sR = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, s.Size);

      var mD = m.LockBits(mR, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
      var sD = s.LockBits(sR, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

      int* m0 = (int*)mD.Scan0, s0 = (int*)sD.Scan0;

      for (var x = mR.Left; x < mR.Right; x++)
         for (var y = mR.Top; y < mR.Bottom; y++)
            if (*(m0 + x + y * mR.Width) == *s0)
               if (CheckSubImage(m0, s0, mR, sR, x, y, out var result))
                  return result;

      m.UnlockBits(mD);
      s.UnlockBits(sD);
   }

   return null;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = GetPoint(@"D:\TestImages\Main.bmp", @"D:\TestImages\1159-980.bmp");
```

The results are about 100 times faster than simple 4 loop approach you had.

**Note**, this uses the unsafe keyword so you will have to set project to allow unsafe.

**Disclaimer** : This could be optimized more also, also it could be done in parallel, and obviously would be faster on the gpu. the point was its the algorithm that matters not the processor

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will try it. My existing code was taking too much CPU for finding a 50 X 50 image in a 1600 X 900 screenshot. So, I had to find either a better algorithm or use GPU for the 4-Loop method.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can use the GPU from C#

[cmsoft](http://www.cmsoft.com.br/opencl-tutorial/) has a tutorial for their library here

You will need write some instructions in OpenCL

You may also need to check you have a [driver/runtime](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) for opencl ([or for AMD](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/OpenCL2-Driver.aspx))

The code is mostly boilerplate stuff. Pretty straight forward. You may spend more time getting the dependencies installed than writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

This method called correlation and can be optimized by FFT.
Correlation can be simply converted to convolution  by rotation of the kernel. So if both the Complete_Image and Small_Image padded by enough zeros and the Small_Image rotated by 180 degree, then the IFFT of the product of the FFT of the two images can compute the entire correlation image in O(n log n) order. Where n is the size of the image(Length*Height). The main correlation problem has the order of nearly n*n.